# Instantiating Values on Isolate Scope

Tags: angularjs

I am having some trouble understanding how to instantiate values on isolate scopes.

The code in this example can be found [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/lhmT3cHXsRfJg97uYFxi?p=preview).

In `testA` since we have the controller setting `$scope.name` and `$scope.alt` I would expect to see AltA and Sam for the name. Instead `alt` isn't available, and `name` is coming from the parent.

`testB` works as expected. We have an inherited scope.

`testC` also doesn't work as expected as we expect the name to come from the `name` attribute, but instead it's using the `name` on the root controller.

Any help on where my concepts are wrong?

Html:

```
<div ng-controller="RootController">
  <h1>name on RootController = {{ name }}</h1>

  <div test-a="test-a">
    <h1>TestA</h1>
    <h2>name is: {{ name }}, expected is Sam</h2>
    <h2>alt is: {{ alt }}, expected AltA</h2>
  </div>

  <div test-b="test-b">
    <h1>TestB</h1>
    <h2>name is: {{ name }}, expected is Dave</h2>
    <h2>scope.alt is: {{ alt }}, expected is AltB</h2>
  </div>

  <div test-c="test-c" name="Homer">
    <h1>TestC</h1>
    <h2>name is: {{ name }}, expect Homer</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);



app.controller('RootController', function($scope) {

  //this is set first... 
  $scope.name = "Bob";

});

// Isolate scope, but why is name not working in controller instantiation
app.directive('testA', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {},
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.name = "Sam"; // Instead it's using value from parent scope
      $scope.alt = "AltA"; // Can't be acccessed?
    }
  };
});

// Inherited scope, works as expected
app.directive('testB', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.name = 'Dave'; // Overwrites the value on our scope, like we expect
      $scope.alt = "AltB"; // Sets this on our scope, like we expect
    }
  };
});

// Isolate scope, name instantiated from attr
app.directive('testC', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope:  { name: '@' }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working fork of your plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/Oecr5F2tcyioS30g2mYG?p=preview

You need to put the templates into the directives with isolate scope, or use transclude.

This is what I changed about your first directive, for example:

```
app.directive('testA', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<div><h1>TestA</h1><h2>name is: {{ name }}, expected is Sam</h2><h2>alt is: {{ alt }}, expected AltA</h2></div>',
    scope: {},
    link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {
      $scope.name = "Sam"; // Instead it's using value from parent scope
      $scope.alt = "AltA"; // Can't be acccessed?
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: This makes total sense, don't know why I didn't realize it. Had been banging my head on it for far too long.